# Apache Camel upgrade from 2.13.0 to 2.17.2 route not working

Tags: web-services, xpath, routes, apache-camel, cxf

after upgrading the Java implementation of Camel from 2.13.0 to 2.17.2 (and cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs from 2.7.10 to 3.1.5, and spring framework from 3.2.8 to 4.3.2), the webapp that is serving as a proxy stopped working correctly.

The app is supposed to intercept a webservice request, modify fields that are defined in a properties file throught the ContextManager class, and forward the request to the correct endpoint.

After the upgrade, the app is unable to set the missing fields in the original request, thus returning the following message: "REQUEST_MESSAGE_NOT_COMPLIANT_WITH_SCHEMA - Your request message does not comply to the web service schema".

This is of course expected since the missing fields are not being set.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

**The problem seems to be coming from the xpath method which in the previous version returned the correct node where some information needs to be set and now is returning null.**

My Camel route definition is as follows:

**CreditLimitRequestServiceRoute.class**

```
public class CreditLimitRequestServiceRoute extends AbstractEHRoute {

    @Autowired
    private ContextManager contextManager;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        Namespaces ns = new Namespaces("ns1", "http://ehsmartlink/commonError");

        onException(SoapFault.class)
            .to("consoleflux:message?level=ERROR&text=${exception.message}&content=${exception.detail}")
            .setHeader("soapFaultDetail", simple("${exception.detail}"))
            .choice()
                .when(and(header("soapFaultDetail").isNotNull(), xpath("//ns1:commonError/errorType/text() = 'BusinessError'", ns, "soapFaultDetail")))
                    .to("consoleflux:finish?ignoreContent=true")
                .otherwise()
                    .to("consoleflux:error?ignoreContent=true");

        onException(Exception.class)
            .to("consoleflux:error");

        from("cxf:bean:creditLimitRequestServiceProxy?dataFormat=PAYLOAD").routeId("creditLimitRequestServiceRoute")
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Invocation du WS").streamCaching()
            .to("consoleflux:start?source=SOA&dest=EH&type=CREDIT_LIMIT")
            .to("consoleflux:message?ignoreContent=true&text=Affectation du Contexte EH")
            .setHeader("context").xpath("//context")
            .bean(contextManager, "setContext")
            .to("consoleflux:message?ignoreContent=true&text=Invocation du WS EH ${headers.operationName}")
            .to("cxf:bean:creditLimitRequestService?dataFormat=PAYLOAD")
            .to("consoleflux:finish");

    }

}
```

**AbstractEHRoute.class**

```
public abstract class AbstractEHRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    protected XPathBuilder xpath(String text, Namespaces namespaces, String headerName) {
        XPathBuilder xpath = XPathBuilder.xpath(text).namespaces(namespaces);
        xpath.setHeaderName(headerName);
        return xpath;
    }

}
```

**ContextManager**

```
package com.stef.soa.eh.integration.beans;

import static com.google.common.base.Objects.firstNonNull;
import static com.google.common.base.Strings.isNullOrEmpty;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.apache.camel.Header;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import com.google.common.base.Preconditions;
import com.google.common.collect.Maps;

@Component
public class ContextManager {

    private static final String USER_NAME = "userName";  
    private static final String USER_PASSWORD = "userPassword";
    private static final String LANGUAGE_TEXT_IDENTIFIER = "languageTextIdentifier";
    private static final String TRANSACTION_IDENTIFIER = "transactionIdentifier";
    private static final String POLICIY_IDENTIFIER = "policyIdentifier";
    private static final String POLICY_EXTENSION_IDENTIFIER = "policyExtensionIdentifier";
    private static final String POLICY_EHBU_IDENTIFIER = "policyEHBUIdentifier";
    private static final String IP_ADRESS = "ipAdress";

    @Value("${eh.context.userName}")
    private String userName;

    @Value("${eh.context.userPassword}")
    private String userPassword;

    @Value("${eh.context.languageTextIdentifier}")
    private String languageTextIdentifier;

    @Value("${eh.context.policyIdentifier}")
    private String policyIdentifier;

    @Value("${eh.context.policyExtensionIdentifier}")
    private String policyExtensionIdentifier;

    @Value("${eh.context.policyEHBUIdentifier}")
    private String policyEHBUIdentifier;

    @Value("${eh.context.ipAdress}")
    private String ipAdress;

    public void setContext(@Header("context") Node context) {

        Preconditions.checkNotNull(context, "Le contexte doit être renseigné");

        // Suppression des noeuds enfants avec sauvegarde les valeurs courantes dans une map
        Map<String, String> currentValues = Maps.newHashMap();
        NodeList list = context.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = list.getLength() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            Node child = list.item(i);
            if (child.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && !isNullOrEmpty(child.getTextContent())) {
                currentValues.put(child.getNodeName(), child.getTextContent());
            }
            context.removeChild(child);
        }

        // Ajout des noeuds enfants
        appendChild(context, USER_NAME, userName, currentValues);
        appendChild(context, USER_PASSWORD, userPassword, currentValues);
        appendChild(context, LANGUAGE_TEXT_IDENTIFIER, languageTextIdentifier, currentValues);
        appendChild(context, TRANSACTION_IDENTIFIER, UUID.randomUUID().toString(), currentValues);
        appendChild(context, POLICIY_IDENTIFIER, policyIdentifier, currentValues);
        appendChild(context, POLICY_EXTENSION_IDENTIFIER, policyExtensionIdentifier, currentValues);
        appendChild(context, POLICY_EHBU_IDENTIFIER, policyEHBUIdentifier, currentValues);
        appendChild(context, IP_ADRESS, ipAdress, currentValues);
    }

    private void appendChild(Node node, String name, String value, Map<String, String> currentValues) {
        Document document = node.getOwnerDocument();
        Element child = document.createElement(name);
        child.setTextContent(firstNonNull(currentValues.get(name), value));
        node.appendChild(child);
    }

}
```

**context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:eh.properties, file:///${eh.home}/conf/eh.properties"
        ignore-resource-not-found="true" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.stef.soa.eh" />

    <context:annotation-config />

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/eh/spring/broker.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/eh/spring/camel.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/eh/spring/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/soa-console-flux-client/spring/context.xml"/>

</beans>
```

**camel.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring 
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd" >

    <!-- Camel Context -->
    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="ehContext">
        <properties>
            <property key="org.apache.camel.xmlconverter.output.indent" value="yes"/>
            <property key="org.apache.camel.xmlconverter.output.{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount" value="4"/>
        </properties>
        <package>com.stef.soa.eh.integration</package>
    </camelContext>

</beans>
```

**cxf.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
    xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
    xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd" >

    <!-- Serveur Proxy, Certificat -->
    <http:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
        <http:client ProxyServer="${proxy.host}" ProxyServerPort="${proxy.port}" 
            ConnectionTimeout="${http.client.connectionTimeout}" ReceiveTimeout="${http.client.receiveTimeout}" />
        <http:proxyAuthorization>
            <sec:UserName>${proxy.username}</sec:UserName>
            <sec:Password>${proxy.password}</sec:Password>
        </http:proxyAuthorization>
        <http:tlsClientParameters>
            <sec:keyManagers keyPassword="${eh.keyStore.password}">
                <sec:keyStore type="pkcs12" password="${eh.keyStore.password}" file="${eh.home}/${eh.keyStore.file}" />
            </sec:keyManagers>
        </http:tlsClientParameters>
    </http:conduit>

    <!-- Services Proxy et Cible -->

    <cxf:cxfEndpoint 
        id="creditLimitRequestServiceProxy" 
        address="/creditLimitRequestService" 
        wsdlURL="META-INF/eh/wsdl/CreditLimitRequestService/EH_SMARTLINK_CreditLimitRequestServiceV4.wsdl" 
        serviceName="ns:CreditLimitRequestServiceV4"
        endpointName="ns:CreditLimitRequestServiceV4"
        xmlns:ns="http://ehsmartlink/CreditLimitRequestService/v4"
    />

    <cxf:cxfEndpoint 
        id="creditLimitRequestService" 
        address="${eh.creditLimitRequestService.url}"
        wsdlURL="META-INF/eh/wsdl/CreditLimitRequestService/EH_SMARTLINK_CreditLimitRequestServiceV4.wsdl"
        serviceName="ns:CreditLimitRequestServiceV4"
        endpointName="ns:CreditLimitRequestServiceV4"
        xmlns:ns="http://ehsmartlink/CreditLimitRequestService/v4"
        loggingFeatureEnabled="true"
    />

    <cxf:cxfEndpoint 
        id="customerListRetrieveServiceProxy" 
        address="/customerListRetrieveService" 
        wsdlURL="META-INF/eh/wsdl/CustomerListRetrieveService/CustomerListRetrieveV2.wsdl" 
        serviceName="ns:CustomerListRetrieveServiceV2"
        endpointName="ns:CustomerListRetrieveServiceV2"
        xmlns:ns="http://ehsmartlink/CustomerListRetrieve/v2"
    />

    <cxf:cxfEndpoint 
        id="customerListRetrieveService" 
        address="${eh.customerListRetrieveService.url}"
        wsdlURL="META-INF/eh/wsdl/CustomerListRetrieveService/CustomerListRetrieveV2.wsdl"
        serviceName="ns:CustomerListRetrieveServiceV2"
        endpointName="ns:CustomerListRetrieveServiceV2"
        xmlns:ns="http://ehsmartlink/CustomerListRetrieve/v2"
        loggingFeatureEnabled="true"
    />

    <cxf:cxfEndpoint 
        id="firstEuroListRepertoireReadServiceProxy" 
        address="/firstEuroListRepertoireReadService" 
        wsdlURL="META-INF/eh/wsdl/FirstEuroListRepertoireReadService/EH_SMARTLINK_FirstEuroListRepertoireReadService-v1.wsdl" 
        serviceName="ns:FirstEuroListRepertoireReadService-v1"
        endpointName="ns:FirstEuroListRepertoireReadServicePort-v1_soap11"
        xmlns:ns="http://eulerhermes.com/SMARTLINK/services/FirstEuroListRepertoireReadService/v1"
    />

    <cxf:cxfEndpoint 
        id="firstEuroListRepertoireReadService" 
        address="${eh.firstEuroListRepertoireReadService.url}"
        wsdlURL="META-INF/eh/wsdl/FirstEuroListRepertoireReadService/EH_SMARTLINK_FirstEuroListRepertoireReadService-v1.wsdl" 
        serviceName="ns:FirstEuroListRepertoireReadService-v1"
        endpointName="ns:FirstEuroListRepertoireReadServicePort-v1_soap11"
        xmlns:ns="http://eulerhermes.com/SMARTLINK/services/FirstEuroListRepertoireReadService/v1"
        loggingFeatureEnabled="true"
    />

    <cxf:cxfEndpoint 
        id="firstEuroListRepertoireUpdateServiceProxy" 
        address="/firstEuroListRepertoireUpdateService" 
        wsdlURL="META-INF/eh/wsdl/FirstEuroListRepertoireUpdateService/EH_SMARTLINK_FirstEuroListRepertoireUpdateService-v1.wsdl" 
        serviceName="ns:FirstEuroListRepertoireUpdateService-v1"
        endpointName="ns:FirstEuroListRepertoireUpdateServicePort-v1"
        xmlns:ns="http://eulerhermes.com/SMARTLINK/services/FirstEuroListRepertoireUpdateService/v1"
    />

    <cxf:cxfEndpoint 
        id="firstEuroListRepertoireUpdateService" 
        address="${eh.firstEuroListRepertoireUpdateService.url}"
        wsdlURL="META-INF/eh/wsdl/FirstEuroListRepertoireUpdateService/EH_SMARTLINK_FirstEuroListRepertoireUpdateService-v1.wsdl"
        serviceName="ns:FirstEuroListRepertoireUpdateService-v1"
        endpointName="ns:FirstEuroListRepertoireUpdateServicePort-v1"
        xmlns:ns="http://eulerhermes.com/SMARTLINK/services/FirstEuroListRepertoireUpdateService/v1"
        loggingFeatureEnabled="true"
     /> 

    <cxf:cxfEndpoint 
        id="limitDetailReadServiceProxy" 
        address="/limitDetailReadService"
        wsdlURL="META-INF/eh/wsdl/LimitDetailReadService/EH_SMARTLINK_LimitDetailReadService-v2.wsdl" 
        serviceName="ns:LimitDetailReadService-v2"
        endpointName="ns:LimitDetailReadServicePort-v2"
        xmlns:ns="http://eulerhermes.com/SMARTLINK/services/LimitDetailReadService/v2"
    />

    <cxf:cxfEndpoint 
        id="limitDetailReadService" 
        address="${eh.limitDetailReadService.url}"
        wsdlURL="META-INF/eh/wsdl/LimitDetailReadService/EH_SMARTLINK_LimitDetailReadService-v2.wsdl" 
        serviceName="ns:LimitDetailReadService-v2"
        endpointName="ns:LimitDetailReadServicePort-v2"
        xmlns:ns="http://eulerhermes.com/SMARTLINK/services/LimitDetailReadService/v2"
        loggingFeatureEnabled="true"
    />

</beans>
```